# Are myosatellite cells myoblasts or do they differentiate into myoblasts?

Tags: cell-biology, muscles

Can satellite cells immediately fuse to a myotube/myofiber (meaning it is a myoblast already) or do they differentiate into a myoblast first and then fuse to myotubes/myofibers?

Comment: Where and how have you looked for an answer to this question already?

Comment: Why? I have looked at the (many, slightly different) definitions for what a myoblast is, which leads me to conclude (without certainty) that a myosatellite is a myoblast. I have searched this specific question but of course nothing has come up. I am doing a research project on cultured meat, and all the sources I am using do not mention specifically or imply what a myoblast is. Wikipedia says that myosatellite cells differentiate into myoblasts, from what the definition of a myoblast is it doesn't really add up.

Comment: Why -- so that potential answerers know how much you already know about the topic. It gives them a place to start with their answer. See http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I see, thanks. I am not at university yet, so I am a beginner when it comes to research. I don't know much about muscle fibres at all, or stem cells.